# How to improve my Swimming technique? Help please

Tags: technique, swimming

1. I have a problem breathing inside the water, I have difficulty in exhaling (incomplete exhaling) which creates a lot of problem while swimming.
2. If I stop going the swimming pool (say for 1 month), I feel that whatever I know, I forgot completely and it happens.
3. I try all the strokes but not confident even a single one.

Can you give me some valuable tips? I want to achieve perfection in it.

(I do lots of running and exercise. I feel that stamina can be not a issue here)

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend Total Immersion Swimming or similar programs.

1. stop kicking hard, it's a waste of energy and oxygen.
2. find your natural buoyancy point and swim there. Any effort in swimming UP is not moving you forward. Let you head be all or mostly underwater. Relax.
3. in freestyle (crawl) your body should be rolling side-to-side with each arm pull, so to breathe you are just rolling your face out of the water, not lifting your head. This helps you maintain natural buoyancy and stops you wasting energy swimming up (to raise your head)
4. focus the effort in your arms on moving water behind you, and avoid moving water up, down or to the sides as this wastes energy and creates drag.
5. Keep you body as horizontal as possible. If your feet drop just 10 degrees you're fighting against 2-3 times the resistance as when you are perfectly horizontal.
   Swim smooth.

Answer (score 3):

1. Focus on exhaling.  For a set number of laps focus just on breathing.  Make it a goal to blow out as much breath as possible.
2. Do not miss a month.  Seriously.  Practice makes permanent.  You have to swim regularly until your muscles remember what to do without your brain.  There is no shortcut here.
3. You will get there.  It is good to work on all strokes rather than just one, but that does mean that the time devoted to each stroke is less than if you focused on just one.

Improvement requires consistency in practice.  If possible create a schedule so that swimming is a primary form of exercise and other things like running are the back-up activities.